# stdClass object and Shadow Copy strange output

Tags: php, oop, shadow-copy

I have following `stdClass` object and its assignment using reference object. But once after `unset`ting `unset($A);` still `$B` outputs the previous values of `$A` even a New value is assigned to `$A`'s `->foo` property. See the trace below.

```
<?php
$A = new stdclass;
$A->foo = 'AAA';
echo "Ouput $ A:";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($A);

/*
stdClass Object
(
    [foo] => AAA
)
*/

$B = &$A;
unset($A);

$A = new stdclass;
$A->foo = 'aaa';
echo "after unset $ A and again assigning new value. Ouput $ A:";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($A);
/*   prints like
stdClass Object
(
    [foo] => aaa
)
*/

echo "Ouput $ B:";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($B);
/*  prints like 
stdClass Object
(
    [foo] => AAA
)
*/
```

**Edit:**

Question is that `$B` was assigned a reference of `$A` but after unset of `$A`

1. How it can print values of Previously assigned value of `$A`?
2. If `$A` is unset and if `$B` is going to print value of `$A` then it should print new value of `$A`?

As we know in case of `Shadow Copy` if `source` object is `vanished/destroyed` then a `reference` object cannot point to a location where `source` object was pointing.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @Oswald, see the updated question at below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than saying `unset($A)`, set it to `NULL`. Unset has so many different behaviors in different cases, its [**manual**](http://php.net/unset) is worth a look.

```
$A=NULL;
//unset($A);
```

**[Fiddle](http://codepad.org/wtgChHs9)**

Comment: So here, How could we differentiate `$A=NULL;` and `unset($A);`?

Comment: NULL just gets the job done right away whereas unset checks for many different conditions and unsets differently based on different situations. Have a look at it's referenced manual

Comment: @NullVoid `$A=null` will assign `null` to `$A` (instantly removes its previous value, it'll affect also references). `unset($A)` will just mark variable as `deleted` but will not remove its value (it'll be inaccessible but will still be in memory until GC will delete it).

Comment: Also `unset` will not affect references.

Comment: So it does means that it is better to set `NULL` in this type of situation rather than `unset`ting it, right?

Comment: Unsetting a variable that's referenced somewhere else too might not unset it completely and hence unset in this case may not be used

Answer (score 1):

> How it can print values of Previously assigned value of $A?

The object that is identified by `$A` is referenced by `$B`. That's why `unset($A)` cannot garbage collect the object.

> If $A is unset and if $B is going to print value of $A then it should print new value of $A?

No, `unset` breaks the connection between `$A` and `$B`. After that, `$A = new stdclass` creates a new variable (that happens to have the same name).

Comment: So can we say that `Memory` were occupied for both objects `$A` and `$B` differently? Because this is not a case of `Shadow Copy`.

Comment: `unset` doesn't break connection between variables. But you can say that it break connection to place in memory to which both variables was pointing.

Comment: @ElonThan Ok. So Can I conclude that both objects were pointing to same location. But by `unset($A);` only `$A` has broken connection to location where it was pointing previously and `$B` is still pointing to same location referenced by `$A', right?

Comment: `$A` and `$B`  contain object identifiers, not objects. Whether an object is destroyed depends on whether a variable exists, that holds the object identifier of the object.